# OpenMP (C++) directives equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, openmp

what is  equivalent of this openMp directives in c# ?

```
     #pragma omp parallel {
                // codes here

               }
```

Comment: No clue. Preprocessor directives are rarely used in C#, so there is probably no direct translation. Perhaps you could explain what that directive does?

Comment: The closest thing would be using [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19305674/3764814) for a similar question.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski thanks that was a good link

Answer (score 0):

OpenMP is not part of standard C++. Rather, it's a set of APIs and language *extensions* which have been specified and standardized for C, C++ and Fortran. None of these languages are required to support OpenMP, and there are no standardized OpenMP language extensions for C# or other languages. Some languages (especially newer ones) have built-in support for parallelization, so don't need OpenMP. Other languages (especially functional ones) have sufficiently powerful syntax that language extensions are unnecessary, and libraries can offer similar functionality.

Comment: You must be joking! I've spent the whole day trying to find a way as easy as OpenMP to add things in parallel in C#.. All that fancy stuff don't come close to the ease and performance of OpenMP.